# SQL: How to return matching AND non-matching rows with WHERE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

To clarify the title, I have a table of computers, and a table of updates. I need to see which computers have a specific update applied and which computers do not.

I have the following query, which doesn't return the `NULL` rows for `f_logsoftware`.

```sql
SELECT 
    f_logmachine, f_logsoftware
FROM  
    tb_computers c
LEFT JOIN 
    tb_softwareinstalls s ON c.f_assetID = s.f_logmachine
WHERE 
    f_logsoftware = 'Java (7.0.750)'
```

The above returns something like this:

```
f_logmachine     f_logsoftware
-------------------------------
10001            Java (7.0.750)
10003            Java (7.0.750)
10005            Java (7.0.750)
10007            Java (7.0.750)
```

But I'm hoping for output like this:

```
f_logmachine     f_logsoftware
-------------------------------
10001            Java (7.0.750)
10002            NULL
10003            Java (7.0.750)
10004            NULL
10005            Java (7.0.750)
10006            NULL
10007            Java (7.0.750)
```

I've tried every combination of "JOIN" I could think of, but I'm stumped.

Comment: clarify your question, I mean show us the structure of tb_computers and tb_softwareinstalls. to which table does `f_logsoftware` field belongs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it doesn't show `NULL`, because you are filtering those results: `WHERE f_logsoftware = 'Java (7.0.750)'`, and `NULL` is not equal to `'Java (7.0.750)'`. 
You should filter the results before joining:

```
SELECT c.f_assetID as f_logmachine, f_logsoftware
FROM tb_computers c
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *
            FROM tb_softwareinstalls
            WHERE f_logsoftware = 'Java (7.0.750)') s 
    ON c.f_assetID = s.f_logmachine
ORDER BY c.f_assetID
```

Comment: Your query returns the results as:
`f_logmachine     f_logsoftware
---------------------------------------------
NULL             NULL
NULL             NULL
NULL             NULL
10001            Java (7.0.750)
10003            Java (7.0.750)
10005            Java (7.0.750)
10007            Java (7.0.750)'

EDIT: Well that didn't format properly

Comment: @Beems And that's what you want?, are you asking on how to use `ORDER BY`?. `ORDER BY f_logmachine`

Comment: Sorry, the formatting above isn't proper. It's not returning the results as expected above - it returns two NULL values, one in each column. There is no f_logmachine listed for the NULL software install.

Comment: @Beems So, `f_logmachine` comes from the `tb_softwareinstalls`??, then why are you even using the `tb_computers` table?

Comment: Because `tb_softwareinstalls` doesn't contain the machines that didn't get the software installed. I need to get a list of the machines that received the update as well as the machines that didn't.

Comment: @Beems then you needed to use the column from the computers table. Just as I did on the answer update

Comment: Your updated answer fixed it - thank you. So can you please explain why setting the alias there changed the result?

Comment: @Beems It has nothing to do with giving it an alias. I'm using the column from the `computers` table instead of the column from joined table (which, by design, will give you nulls if there is no match)

Answer (score 0):

How about searching for NULL too:

```
SELECT  f_logmachine ,
        f_logsoftware
FROM    tb_computers c
        LEFT JOIN tb_softwareinstalls s ON c.f_assetID = s.f_logmachine
WHERE   f_logsoftware = 'Java (7.0.750)'
        OR f_logsoftware IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `WHERE f_logsoftware = 'Java (7.0.750)'` does not restrict the returned rows it looks odd in a where clause. What you want to do is map  `'Java (7.0.750)'` to itself and every other value of `f_logsoftware` to null.

Try using 'CASE .. WHEN .. THEN .. ELSE .. END' in the projection.